# Where to store RSpec test files (CSVs, JSONs etc.)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, unit-testing, csv, rspec

I am writing some specs that involve CSVs generated by my app. I mocked these files and currently have their output in my test files. But I feel the approach is not right, I would like to have these mocks available to other specs as well, in some kind of shared spec folder.

So, what is your suggestion on this? Where to store test files useful for several specs?

Comment: Anywhere accessible by the tests. `spec/support` is usually a good candidate.

Comment: Is this a used scenario or it's preferred to mock them directly in the spec files?

Comment: Maybe then to a `spec/fixtures` folder, since these are static files?

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your initial question as well as your follow-up question in the comments ("Is this a used scenario or it's preferred to mock them directly in the spec files"), I would consider two things:  is the output very large (say, longer than ten lines), or is it repeated across multiple test files? If either of those things are true, create a Ruby file containing a Plain Ol' Ruby Object (say, a Ruby hash or array stored as a constant inside a module), or a JSON, YAML, or CSV file, and store it in `spec/support` (`test/support` for Minitesters out there).

If neither of those things are true, then I think having the setup data in the test file is great because users don't have to unnecessarily look through multiple files to figure out how a test works.

I don't like the idea of `spec/fixtures` for storing CSV files since `fixtures` has a very specific meaning in the Ruby vernacular.